# Does anyone know where I can find a list of wonderous items by caster level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting, artificer

I'm starting a new game as a fifth level artificer (and fifth level wizard so I had WBL for a level 10) and was trying to figure out what magic items I might want to spend my WBL on. However since Pathfinder has 1544 wondrous objects and presumably only some of them have a caster level requirement less than or equal to 7 I haven't been able to find which ones I should even be considering. Does anyone know of where I could find a list by caster level?

Comment: Usually, [shopping questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7414/8610) (that is, typically, any question looking for a list off-site resources) are quickly closed, but I thought that this question indicated a deeper issue that needed addressing. If this is too bold of an assumption, and there's a *different* reason such a database is needed, please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to indicate what you want to accomplish with the build, and ask about suitable items?

Comment: @Jason_c_o Last seen Sep 13 '19 at 22:34

Comment: @ThomasMarkov That doesn't mean it won't be helpful for people that come along. I got here from the queue. I also don't click the profile of every asker on every question I look at. I find your comment unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

#### A convenient, easy-to-sort, free, quick-loading database of wondrous items that's *organized by caster level* may exist *somewhere*, but this reader suspects that such a database won't be of much help

It sounds like the issue here is the belief that a magic item's listed caster level is a requirement for the magic item's creation. In fact, this is *not* typically the case: The *Pathfinder* SRD on [Magic Item Creation](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html#magic-item-creation), in part, says "A creator can create an item at a lower caster level than her own, but never lower than the minimum level needed to cast the needed spell [that's required to create the magic item]." Hence only those magic items that *have* a caster level as an *actual* requirement for their creation *require* the creator to *possess* that caster level; other magic items can be created so as to possess a caster level anywhere *from* the minimum caster level needed to cast the spells required for their creation *to* the caster's actual level. (However, note that creating a magic item at lower, nonstandard caster level may affect the magic item's performance.)

For example, a [*cape of the mountebank*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/wondrousItems.html#cape-of-the-mountebank) that normally has a caster level 9 can be created by a level 7 wizard who's capable of providing the *cape*'s required [*dimension door*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door/) spell because having caster level 9 is *not* a requirement for the *cape*'s creation! When that wizard 7 creates that *cape*, that *cape* has *both* a minimum *and* a maximum caster level of 7. (Such a *cape*'s range—and perhaps capacity—would be similarly altered by this lowered caster level to a degree that would make it inferior to a typical, off-the-rack *cape of the mountebank*, by the way.) However, a typical [*ioun stone*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/wondrousItems.html#ioun-stones) has as one its requirements that the creator *actually* possess a caster level of 12, making that requirement fixed and—without bypassing that requirement by increasing the Spellcraft skill check needed to create the item—inescapable.

In sum, a list of wondrous items that themselves possess a caster level of 7 or less doesn't actually give you a definitive picture of what wondrous items your PC *can* create. However, a list of wondrous items that includes their spell requirements would.

***Note:*** I can't vouch for the completeness or usability of [this database](http://www.pathfindercommunity.net/home/databases/magic-items) (last updated Dec. 2017) nor [this database](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-items-db/) (last updated Mar. 2014)— both of which are massive and take a long time *to load—but they seem like the kinds of thing that might be of help.*

Answer (score 2):

I built [my Collection of items from Pathfinder](https://sortekanin.com/collection/items/) for exactly this kind of purpose.

With this database you can filter for wondrous items with a caster level of 7 or below, with a maximum price of 30000 (WBL for 10 is 62000 but you probably don't want to spend all your gold on one item). You could also filter for a minimum price of 5000 (to filter away less useful items) and only from the Core Rulebook or Ultimate Equipment. This is the query: https://sortekanin.com/collection/items/?min_price=5000&max_price=30000&kinds%5B%5D=Wondrous+Item&Core+Rulebook=require&Ultimate+Equipment=require&max_caster_level=7

But you can construct the filters yourself to your liking.